# Indiana Jones - Raiders of the Lost Ark - Rock material

Tags: texturing, materials

I'm trying to recreate a rocky material from the Indiana Jones and the Raiders of the Lost Ark movie, but I'm unable to come close to it. I've never really faced issues recreating materials, but this one is one hell of a PITA!

On the images is what I'm trying to replicate.

[image: Rock reference]

You can take a better look at the reference here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mC1ikwQ5Zgc&t=53s

How would you go on about creating such material?
(BTW, the grooves/carving isn't needed, only the rock material itself)

And how would you light the base?

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Maybe try a *Noise* plugged into a *ColorRamp* plugged into a *Diffuse*, mix it with a *Glossy* with a *Layer Weight* as factor, give both the *Diffuse* and the *Glossy* a bit of *Noise* as *Bump*:

[image]